# Work out how much it took to pay builder with formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Emma is employing Ian to build a deck at her house.

She provides all the building material

She pays Ian $P for the number of hours h that he works.

She also pays Ian's travels fee to her home each day. Ian works for 8 hours each day.

He knows the deck will take more than 4 hours to build.

To help Emma know how much she can expect to pay, Ian provides her the following table:

Number of hours worked (h)                  Payment (p)

```
    4                                      160
    5                                      185
    6                                      210
    7                                      235
    8                                      260
    9                                      345
    10                                     3770
```

How much would Emma pay if the work took 30 hours?

I am just confused about how to find out how much you need to pay from travel. Do you pay him at the end of 8 hours or every 5 hours.

So would it be:

30x25=750   (Labour)

3x60=180    (Travel)

TOtal- 930

Is this correct or have I done something incorrect with the travel fee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think the last line is a typo and should be 370, not 3770.

We can see from the table that each additional hour of labor costs
\$25, so you've worked that out correctly.  Then for 4 hours work,
the fee is \$160, which means the travel fee is $160 - 4\times 25 = 60$,
so you've work that out correctly two.  If he works 8 hours per day, then in three days, he can put in only 24 hours.  So he'll have to make the trip 4 times and put in 6 hours on the last day.  So the travel fee should be $4\times 60 = 240$.  So I the final total is $30\times 25 + 240 = 990.$  I think you just missed a day of travel.